# Bus error (core dumped)

Tags: synaptic

I am not able to remove any installed application and also some applications like Synaptic package manager isn't starting. The error message shown is "Bus error(core dumped). Earlier the system was not rebooting property, as it was going in busy box mode, but somehow I managed to start the system. But now Bus error is showing up and each time I start the system, it goes again in busy box mode.

I am using 16.04 LTS. Thanks for helping.
Regards!

Comment: Sounds like your hard drive is corrupt.

Comment: BUT I'm able to play videos and music. I'm just not able to INSTALL or UNINSTALL APPLICATIONS.

Comment: I tried updating the system using terminal. It worked up to 13% and then same error "Bus error (core dumped)"

Comment: It's possible that part of the hard drive is messed up or you have buggy Linux drivers. What version of Ubuntu are you using, and on which machine?

Comment: It's 16.04 LTS. 64-Bit